# Use several times global parameter in controller symfony

Tags: symfony, service, controller

I need your help in Symfony controller, there is a way to use a global parameter and get the different value in different method.

Actually I have this.

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
     //Injection of white october bundle

     /** @DI\Inject("white_october_breadcrumbs") */
     private $wob;

     public function indexAction(Request $request)
     {
         $this->wob->addRouteItem("Article", "article_index");
         //Some stuff
     }

     public function addAction(Request $request, $id=0) 
     {
         if($request->get('_route') === "article_add"){
             $this->wob->addRouteItem("Add article", "article_add");
         } else {
             $this->wob->addRouteItem("Edit article", "article_edit");
         }
         //Some stuff
     }

     //Other functions..
}
```

As you can see, actually my breadcrumb only keep the last value of the global parameter `$wob`

Example :

> Home > Article
>
> Home > Edit article

But i want :

> Home > Article > Edit article

Don't know if it's possible

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addAction` is completely separated from `indexAction` and these are different requests, so you cannot expect to keep value of `$wob` property between requests.
In yours example you can make parent only inside the same action:

```
public function addAction(Request $request, $id=0) 
{

    $this->wob->addRouteItem("Article", "article_index");

    if($request->get('_route') === "article_add"){
        $this->wob->addRouteItem("Add article", "article_add");
    } else {
        $this->wob->addRouteItem("Edit article", "article_edit");
    }
     //Some stuff
 }
```

Comment: Mmmmmmh, that's what i thought, that's impossible to link request :( thank you for the explanation !